# IMU sensor LPMS-B2: Unable to connect via bluetooth to Unity application?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect this [IMU sensor](https://lp-research.com/lpms-b2/)  via bluetooth to a Unity implemented application that currently is running in the Unity Editor on a Windows laptop and eventually will be built for Android. 
[Here](https://bitbucket.org/lpresearch/csharplibraryforb2/src/master/) I found some example code (project: *LpSensorCSharp_CommandLine_Example*) which I tested successfully: The output on the console is the desired sensor data. As you can see the connection process is pretty straightforward:

```
    string sensor1Address = "00:04:3E:9B:A3:55";
    LpmsB2 sensor1 = new LpmsB2(sensor1Address);

    // connects to sensor
    int retryCount = 0;
    sensor1.connect();
    while (sensor1.getConnectionStatus() != LpmsB2.SENSOR_STATUS_CONNECTED)
    {
        if (sensor1.getConnectionStatus() == LpmsB2.SENSOR_STATUS_ERROR)
        {
            if (retryCount >= 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to sensor after {0} retries. Terminating bye", retryCount);
                System.Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Error connecting to sensor: {0}", sensor1.getErrorMessage());
            Console.WriteLine("retrying {0}", retryCount);
            retryCount += 1;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }

    sensor1.printConfig();
    String filename = "LpmsB2Log_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".csv";
    using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        while (sensor1.getConnectionStatus() == LpmsB2.SENSOR_STATUS_CONNECTED)
        {
            int nData = sensor1.hasNewData();
            if (nData > 0)
            {
                LpmsData sd = new LpmsData();
                // Here we have our desired data
                sd = ((LpmsData)sensor1.getLpmsBData());
            } 
            else
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to implement the same functionality in Unity, which looks like that (`OnConnect` is listening to a button's `OnClick`):

```
private void OnConnect()
{
    StartCoroutine(Connect());
}

private IEnumerator Connect()
{
    sensor1 = new LpmsB2(sensorAddress);
    // connects to sensor
    int retryCount = 0;
    sensor1.connect();
    while (sensor1.getConnectionStatus() != LpmsB2.SENSOR_STATUS_CONNECTED)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Connection status: {0}", sensor1.getConnectionStatus());
        if (retryCount >= 3)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("Error connecting to sensor after {0} retries. Terminating bye", retryCount);
            break;
        }
        Debug.LogFormat("Error connecting to sensor: {0}", sensor1.getErrorMessage());
        Debug.LogFormat("retrying {0}", retryCount);
        retryCount += 1;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if(sensor1 != null)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Connection status: {0}", sensor1.getConnectionStatus());
        if (sensor1.getConnectionStatus() == LpmsB2.SENSOR_STATUS_CONNECTED)
        {
            int nData = sensor1.hasNewData();
            if (nData > 0)
            {
                LpmsData sd = new LpmsData();
                sd = ((LpmsData)sensor1.getLpmsBData());
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `sensor1.getConnectionStatus()` beginning with its first call always returns `LpmsB2.SENSOR_STATUS_CONNECTING`, whereas `sensor1.getErrorMessage()` always returns `"none"` during the `Connect`. 
 Could you please give me indication what I'm doing wrong in my Unity implementation?